# Athena SDK CTAS query does not create the output file

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I'm trying a CTAS query with **aws Athena SDK(.net)** for creating parquet file.

When the query is submitted & succeed, I can see new table in the Athena console. But in the **aws S3**, the parquet file don't exist.

Below is my Athena query and results.

```
create table new_table 
with(format='parquet', external_location='s3://bucket-name/key-path') 
as select * from table
```

```
Athena console : Time in queue: 0.113 sec / Run time: 1.542 sec / Data scanned: 1.29 KB
Athena SDK     : Time in queue: 0.221 sec / Run time: 1.768 sec / Data scanned: -
```

When I tried the CTAS query with the Athena SDK, scanned data is none & file is not created in external_location.

Comment: Check if Role/User used to run Athena SDK have permissions to create Athena table ( glue:CreateTable) and s3 buckets ("table" bucket and "s3://bucket-name/key-path". Usually, permissions are the culprit but errors are silenced. Ref for permissions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/fine-grained-access-to-glue-resources.html